# Why am I getting an invalid hook call error?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I got the usual "Error: Invalid hook call" but I can't figure out what I did wrong..

I followed this tutorial (french) : https://medium.com/@darksh3ll.js/une-application-multilingue-avec-redux-et-react-redux-hooks-4679d8e59758
but ended up with an invalid hook call anyway, on this bit :
(those buttons are part of the main index.js in the tutorial, but I added them as a component for clarity sake)

```
  const lang = useSelector(state => state.languageReducer.language)
  const dispach = useDispatch
  return (
    <div>
    <div className="btnLang">
//the error show up when i click on one of these
      <button className="btnFr" onClick={(() => dispach({type: "fr"}))}>Français</button>
      <button className="btnEn" onClick={(() => dispach({type: "en"}))}>English</button>
//the rest seems fine...
    </div>
    <div className="btnTitle">
      <h1>{lang}</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

any thoughts ?

Comment: Should be `const dispatch = useDispatch()`

Comment: you should call ```useDispatch``` hook to return the ```dispatch``` function. ```const dispach = useDispatch()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be const dispatch = useDispatch()